# error on importing tensorflow in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, import, tensorflow

i have `ubuntu 14.04` ; But a got this error when I run import tensorflow :

if i'am import a tensorflow

```
>>> import tensorflow
```

.

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xa but this version of numpy is 0x9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

what is the problem and how resolved this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your numpy version to 10 (your current version is 9).